# Confusions in understanding different admin systems

Tags: phpmyadmin, django-admin, admin

I watched a few tutorials about making a dynamic website using PHP. Now first thing they did was, they setup something called phpMyAdmin and then started building a website. Now when I saw the admin interface in that video I thought of Wordpress admin interface which was completely different. Then, after a little bit of googling, I understood that Wordpress admin is completely different than phpMyAdmin.

Okay, now let's pick Facebook. Has Mark Zuckerberg designed his own admin system [something like Wordpress admin] to manage the site or does he use phpMyAdmin?

Now, there is django. I went through its tutorials and found that it already has a 'powerful' admin feature. Now I don't understand is it similar to phpMyAdmin or different (because both look a lot same)? (Yes, before posting this question, I went through some other questions about using django admin with phpMyAdmin but I did not get my doubts clear).

Another thing that is eating me is, if I want to make a CMS something like Wordpress, or say, just like Wordpress, and I want it to offer all the features that Wordpress does, and I don't need the django admin system (it's interface is really pathetic compared to the Wordpress admin interface), so can I design my own admin system or do I need to use only and only django admin?

Really, I am lost and confused.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is just a web-based client for managing mySql.  if you are attempting to make a CMS, from scratch you will likely want to familiarize yourself with this or another tool for managing your DB.  do not confuse the two though, they are not even related.  phpMyAdmin is not a CMS, it is a database tool.

the question is, if you want to create a CMS just like wordpress, why not just use wordpress?

Comment: I would like to build it just as a project and not to make it a competitor of Wordpress. Just a project to get an in-depth exposure to django and python.